# "Moving" a filter from one set to an other set, two equivalent formulations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, filters

By filters I mean filters on sets (not on one fixed set but on arbitrary sets).

Informally saying, this question concerns "moving" a filter from one set to an other set.

I define *rebase* a filter $\mathcal{A}$ (on a set $\mathfrak{A}$) to a set $\mathfrak{B}$ by the formula

$$\mathcal{A} \div \mathfrak{B} = \left\{ X \in \mathscr{P} \mathfrak{B} \,|\,
\exists Y \in \mathcal{A} : Y \subseteq X \right\} .$$

I want to prove that

$$\mathcal{A} \div \mathfrak{B} = [\{ X\cap \mathfrak{B} \,|\, X\in\mathcal{A} \}]_{\mathfrak{B}}$$

where $[F]_{\mathfrak{B}}$ means the filter on $\mathfrak{B}$ induced by the set $F$.

I'd prefer not any arbitrary proof, but a clean "structured" proof, maybe as a series of lemmas.

Comment: Are you assuming any relation between the sets $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$?

Comment: @ArthurFischer: No, to be useful this thing should work for every possible pair of sets $\mathfrak{A}$, $\mathfrak{B}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without conditions on $\mathfrak{A} , \mathfrak{B}$ these families may not be equal.

Suppose that $\mathcal{A}$ is the principal (ultra)filter on $A$ generated by $a \in \mathfrak{A}$, and $\mathfrak{B}$ does not contain $a$.  It it easy to show that $\mathcal{A} \div \mathfrak{B} = \varnothing$ (since no set in $\mathcal{A}$ can be a subset of any subset of $\mathfrak{B}$).  However $\{ X \cap \mathfrak{B} : X \in \mathcal{A} \} = \mathscr{P} ( \mathfrak{A} \cap \mathfrak{B} )$.